# Is there a way to add a silhouette for objects being hidden by AR occlusion in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, augmented-reality

[image: Show a Silhouette When Hidden Using URP Renderer Features]

I'm trying to add a silhouette for virtual objects being hidden by real world objects or human hands.

So something similar to this image, but using AR. For example, I'm using my hand to hide a virtual cube. While my hand is covering the cube, I want a silhouette of the cube to show.

The functionality in the image was done using URP renderer features using Unity 2021.3.15f1.

I tried making a shader following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAh225QNpm0&ab_channel=KetraGames

Sadly, it didn't work when tested using AR. AR occlusion is working properly. Currently, if I put my hand in front of a game object, it will cover it, but it won't show the silhouette.[image: AR Occlusion settings]

I would appreciate any help! Thank you.